# Quoting a command line argument containing a variable that may have both single and double quotes in its expansion

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

After some unsuccesful attempts at quoting the command string correctly, I ended up using the below command to run the identify command on the .jpg files under the working directory, the names of which may contain single and/or double quotes:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
    xterm -e bash -c "identify -verbose \"${f/\"/\\\"}\" | less"
done
```

However, I realized that variable expansion with string replacement construct wasn't POSIX compatible.

So, what is your recommended way to quote such a command line argument that possibly expands to a string with single and double quotes, and what is a POSIX-compatible syntax for the above command?

Comment: How about letting the shell do the for loop: `xterm -e bash -c 'for f in *.jpg; do identify -verbose "$f" | less; done'` instead of opening a new xterm window every time.

Comment: @thisaccounthasbeen Works well if you want info for all images in a single window, plus avoids the nested quotes problem, although I use the command in a plugin script, where I prefer the details of selected images in separate windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the filename as argument to the command string:

```
for f in *.jpg; do
  xterm -e bash -c 'identify -verbose "$1" | less' bash "$f"
done
```